# How to send data from POST to Database with JSON

Tags: php, mysql, json

For my work I'm currently creating a schedular. The schedule looks good and has the info on th right place on the website. The editor of the schedule looks fine, with getting the data.

I am working currently with JSON formatted data, which is stored in a data column inside the schedules table.

Every day has it's own row as 19-8-2022, 20-8-2022, etc. with json data.

No I am at this moment that i need to create a for loop, in order to send the data back with an UPDATE SQL to the database.

This is where I get stuck, I don't know how I can get this loop to work, as the logic is a bit gone in my head.

So the output of the $_POST (with var_export) gives me the following:

```
array ( 
    'announcement1' => 'Donderdag t/m Zondag open tot 21:00', 
    
    'daynote1' => '', 
    'day1' => '15-08', 
    'schstarttime1-1' => '15:00', 
    'schendtime1-1' => '', 
    'schstarttime1-2' => '17:00', 
    'schendtime1-2' => '', 
    'schstarttime1-3' => '17:00', 
    'schendtime1-3' => '', 
    'schemployee1-1' => '5', 
    'schemployee1-2' => '4', 
    'schemployee1-3' => '6', 
    'schnote1-1' => '', 
    'schnote1-2' => '', 
    'schnote1-3' => 'Oproep', 
    'schposition1-1' => 'kitchen', 
    'schposition1-2' => 'kitchen', 
    'schposition1-3' => 'kitchen', 

    'daynote2' => '', 
    'day2' => '16-08', 
    'schstarttime2-1' => '16:00', 
    'schendtime2-1' => '', 
    'schstarttime2-2' => '17:00', 
    'schendtime2-2' => '', 
    'schstarttime2-3' => '17:00', 
    'schendtime2-3' => '', 
    'schemployee2-1' => '5', 
    'schemployee2-2' => '3', 
    'schemployee2-3' => '8', 
    'schnote2-1' => '', 
    'schnote2-2' => '', 
    'schnote2-3' => '', 
    'schposition2-1' => 'kitchen', 
    'schposition2-2' => 'kitchen', 
    'schposition2-3' => 'kitchen',

    'daynote3' => '', 
    'day3' => '17-08', 
    'schstarttime3-1' => '11:00', 
    'schendtime3-1' => '', 
    'schstarttime3-2' => '13:00', 
    'schendtime3-2' => '', 
    'schstarttime3-3' => '16:00', 
    'schendtime3-3' => '', 
    'schstarttime3-4' => '17:00', 
    'schendtime3-4' => '', 
    'schemployee3-1' => '1', 
    'schemployee3-2' => '2', 
    'schemployee3-3' => '5', 
    'schemployee3-4' => '6', 
    'schnote3-1' => 'Opslag', 
    'schnote3-2' => '', 
    'schnote3-3' => 'Sluit', 
    'schnote3-4' => 'Sluit', 
    'schposition3-1' => 'kitchen', 
    'schposition3-2' => 'kitchen', 
    'schposition3-3' => 'kitchen', 
    'schposition3-4' => 'kitchen', 

    'daynote4' => '', 
    'day4' => '18-08', 
    'schstarttime4-1' => '11:00', 
    'schendtime4-1' => '', 
    'schstarttime4-2' => '16:00', 
    'schendtime4-2' => '', 
    'schstarttime4-3' => '16:00', 
    'schendtime4-3' => '', 
    'schstarttime4-4' => '17:00', 
    'schendtime4-4' => '', 
    'schemployee4-1' => '5', 
    'schemployee4-2' => '2', 
    'schemployee4-3' => '3', 
    'schemployee4-4' => '8', 
    'schnote4-1' => '', 
    'schnote4-2' => 'Opslag', 
    'schnote4-3' => '', 
    'schnote4-4' => '', 
    'schposition4-1' => 'kitchen', 
    'schposition4-2' => 'kitchen', 
    'schposition4-3' => 'kitchen', 
    'schposition4-4' => 'kitchen', 

    'daynote5' => '', 
    'day5' => '19-08', 
    'schstarttime5-1' => '11:00', 
    'schendtime5-1' => '', 
    'schstarttime5-2' => '12:00', 
    'schendtime5-2' => '', 
    'schstarttime5-3' => '16:00', 
    'schendtime5-3' => '', 
    'schstarttime5-4' => '16:00', 
    'schendtime5-4' => '', 
    'schemployee5-1' => '5', 
    'schemployee5-2' => '3', 
    'schemployee5-3' => '8', 
    'schemployee5-4' => '2', 
    'schnote5-1' => '', 
    'schnote5-2' => '', 
    'schnote5-3' => 'Sluit', 
    'schnote5-4' => 'Opslag, Sluit', 
    'schposition5-1' => 'kitchen', 
    'schposition5-2' => 'kitchen', 
    'schposition5-3' => 'kitchen', 
    'schposition5-4' => 'kitchen', 

    'daynote6' => '', 
    'day6' => '20-08', 
    'schstarttime6-1' => '11:00', 
    'schendtime6-1' => '', 
    'schstarttime6-2' => '16:00', 
    'schendtime6-2' => '', 
    'schstarttime6-3' => '16:00', 
    'schendtime6-3' => '', 
    'schstarttime6-4' => '17:00', 
    'schendtime6-4' => '', 
    'schemployee6-1' => '2', 
    'schemployee6-2' => '5', 
    'schemployee6-3' => '9', 
    'schemployee6-4' => '8', 
    'schnote6-1' => 'Opslag', 
    'schnote6-2' => '', 
    'schnote6-3' => '', 
    'schnote6-4' => '', 
    'schposition6-1' => 'kitchen', 
    'schposition6-2' => 'kitchen', 
    'schposition6-3' => 'kitchen', 
    'schposition6-4' => 'kitchen', 

    'daynote7' => '', 
    'day7' => '21-08', 
    'schstarttime7-1' => '11:00', 
    'schendtime7-1' => '', 
    'schstarttime7-2' => '14:00', 
    'schendtime7-2' => '', 
    'schstarttime7-3' => '16:00', 
    'schendtime7-3' => '', 
    'schemployee7-1' => '1', 
    'schemployee7-2' => '9', 
    'schemployee7-3' => '2', 
    'schnote7-1' => 'Opslag', 
    'schnote7-2' => 'Sluit', 
    'schnote7-3' => 'Sluit', 
    'schposition7-1' => 'kitchen', 
    'schposition7-2' => 'kitchen', 
    'schposition7-3' => 'kitchen', 
)
```

As you see every word has an number and a minus and a number, the first number says which day it belongs to, the second number is the number of many employees are working, in the first day 1 2 3 means that day works 3 people. And for example 1-1 belongs to a certain person on the specific date with all keys infront of it (schstarttime1-1, schendtime1-1, etc.).

But again, i don't know how to get a for loop working for this and sending them to the database to the right row in the json format in the data column.

**EDIT:**
At the end it needs to be sent to the database like this per employee:

```
{"userid":"[schemployee1-1]", "starttime":"[schstarttime1-1]", "endtime":"[schendtime1-1]", "note":"[schnote1-1]", "position":"[schposition1-1]", "request":"0", "replaceid":""},
```

**EDIT 2:**
At this moment I have those 2 loops:

```
for ($i = 1; $i <=7; $i++) {

    $person = "";
    for ($ii = 1; $ii <=3; $ii++) {
        $person .= '{"userid":"' . $_POST["schemployee" . $i  . "-" .  $ii] . '", "starttime":"' . $_POST["schstarttime" . $i  . "-" .  $ii] . '", "endtime":"' . $_POST["schendtime" . $i  . "-" .  $ii] . '", "note":"' . $_POST["schnote" . $i  . "-" .  $ii] . '", "position":"' . $_POST["schposition" . $i  . "-" .  $ii] . '", "request":"0", "replaceid":""}, ';
    }

    echo "UPATE `schedules` SET `data` = '[" . substr($person, 0, -2) . "]' WHERE `date` = '" . $_POST["day" . $i] . "'<br /><br />";

}
```

With this i get very far, but I have one issue, and that is when the employees are more or less sometimes, there is no same number, so the second loop will crash, with a certain number, I need to have a number that will count the total employees of that day. so that every day will get a total of employees without failing.

Comment: Have you tried to write a loop? Anything at all? To make a super-simple version, start with `for ($i = 1; $i <=7; $i++)`. Then try to use that to echo the names of alll the "daynote" fields, using $i to help you build all of them automatically.

Comment: I've tried that before, but the thing then is I get the values with the for loop, but i don't know about the second number as in the number of employees and how to organize them too.

Comment: Just make a second loop within it to go from 1 to 3, and make the second part with that variable as well

Comment: I can't go from 1 to 3 as 3 is not the constant number of every day, and every week the employees can change of certain days.

Comment: You'll have to loop until it doesn't match any item in the array, then

Comment: Changing it to `for ($ii = 1; isset($_POST["schemployee" . $i  . "-" .  $ii]); $ii++) {` will work then?

Comment: Easiest way to find out is to try it....

Comment: Well it worked but wanted to know if it's a good way, either way thanks for helping :D

Comment: If you have a variable number of rows in the table you could do something similar for that loop too